# How to call function on javascript page from ASP.NET 5 WebAPI

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, websocket, asp.net-core, .net-core

Okay, maybe I'm doing this all wrong, but here goes:

I have a ASP.NET 5 WebAPI project running on dnxcore50. It has one very simple controller, which only implements the `Get()` method:

```
public class Data : Controller {
    public JsonResult Get(){
        return Json(/*some data from EF*/);
    }
}
```

Additionally, I have `index.html` and `myscripts.js` files which host a very simple webpage.
When running the project, it opens on `http://localhost:5000`, I can browse to `index.html` and can call

```
$.getJSON('/api/Data', function(data){
    /*do stuff*/
});
```

All of this works, on all OSX and Windows. So far so good!

Now, what I want: when the API is called (for example a `POST` by another client), it should send a message to the javascript to display an event.
What have I tried:

- setting a flag in the API and polling from the javascript. This seems sub-optimal, but works.
- playing around with `socket.io`, but I cannot find a dnxcore50 compatible way to communicate with it from the controller.
- playing around with HTML5 `WebSockets`, but can't seem to establish communication from the controller.

How can I communicate from ASP.NET 5 (dnxcore50) to a javascript page?

Comment: You've answered your own question. You need to use web sockets or poll.

Comment: Yes, but _how_ can I use websockets on the c# side?

Comment: Microsoft's implementation of web sockets is [signalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr). This may make the communication easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK after some research, I got it working using `SignalR`, as @Liam suggested. 
This is how I got `SignalR` working with ASP.NET Core 1.0.

In `Nuget.config` in project root, add repository for SignalR:

```
 <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v3/index.json" />
```

In `project.json` add reference for SignalR:

```
"dependencies":{
    ...     
    "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-*"
}
```

In `Startup.cs`, register SignalR:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    /* ...other services...*/
    services.AddSignalR(options =>
    {
        options.Hubs.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    /*...other configs...*/
   app.UseSignalR();

}
```

Create a new `Hub` class:

```
public class EventHub : Hub { }
```

From for example a controller, call the hub:

```
private readonly IHubContext hub;       
public ProjectQualityController(IConnectionManager connectionManager)
{
    hub = connectionManager.GetHubContext<EventHub>();
}

public void SendMessage(string value)
{
    hub.Clients.All.sendMessage(value);
}
```

In the javascript file, register to the `sendMessage` event:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.signalR.js"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
     var chat = $.connection.eventHub;
     chat.client.sendMessage = function (message) {
         var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
         alert(encodedMsg)
        };

     // Start the connection.
     $.connection.hub.logging = true;
     $.connection.hub.start()
            .done(function(){ console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id); })
            .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not Connect!'); });
    });       
  </script>
```

Hope this helps someone!